# How to find count of duplicate elements in arraylist and append the dupplicate elements to different textviews

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How to find count of duplicate elements in arraylist and append the duplicate elements to different textviews in andorid.

I have 3 different textview and single arraylist which contains 25 elements with  duplicate elements 
1) How many duplicate values present in arraylist
2) The count of duplicate values should append to textview.

Comment: try writing some java code

Comment: try using a hashmap and storing count as values in the hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections.frequency gives you occurrences of an object in a list.

Another option since this is a small array is to sort it and then iterate, and in the case where `array[i+1] == array[i]`, increase the count of duplicate values.

If elements in this case is not a primitive type, remember to overload the operator.

sample implementation:

```
void countOcc(int []arr) {  
    Set<Integer> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    for(int x : arr) {
        uniques.add(x);
    }

    for(int y : uniques) {
        int totalOcc = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arr), y);
        //gives total occurences for each unique element in the array
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks ..Here is my arraylist arrayinfo33: [5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]. In this arraylist  i want to show individual count of 2's ,3's, 5's are present and total count should be shown in textview ...Here is my code..Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<Integer>(myList);
        for (Integer key : unique) {
            Log.i("checkarryinfo",""+key + ": " + Collections.frequency(myList, key))
        }.....

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the arraylist and find the frequency of each element in arraylist.

Use hashmap for better performance for storing the frequency of elements.

Initialise count to zero. If the frequency of any element is greater than one increment the count. Finally return the count.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
dup = 0
pos = []
for i from 0 to arr.len -1 do
  for c from i + 1 to arr.len -1 do
    if pos.has(c) then 
      break
    fi
    if i == c then
      dup++
      pos.add(c)
    fi
  end
end
```

Rest is up to you. At lot of optimization could be done as well.